# ALAsset thumbnail with high resolution

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have a collectionView with the thumbnails of the pictures in my PhotoLibrary:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    QBAssetCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AssetCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.tag = indexPath.item;
    cell.showsOverlayViewWhenSelected = self.imagePickerController.allowsMultipleSelection;

   // Image
    ALAsset *asset = self.assets[indexPath.item];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]]; 
    cell.imageView.image = image;

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is that the pictures thumbnails are all displayed in low resolution:

[image]

compared to the native Photo Album:

[image]

How can I show a better resolution for my pictures?

PS: I'm using ["QBImagePicker"](https://github.com/questbeat/QBImagePicker).

Answer (score 1):

1.First ,Be sure your QBImagePicker is the latest ,Version above  3.1.0
2.Second ,you can try modify the targetSize Value manually ,like this picture :

[image]

```
// Image
PHAsset *asset = self.fetchResult[indexPath.item];
CGSize itemSize = [(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionView.collectionViewLayout itemSize];


CGSize targetSize = CGSizeScale(itemSize, self.traitCollection.displayScale);
NSLog(@"itemSize  h:%f,w:%f",itemSize.height,itemSize.width);
NSLog(@"targetSize  h:%f,w:%f",targetSize.height,targetSize.width);
targetSize = CGSizeMake(155.0, 155.0);
```

at QBAssetsViewController.m -> -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: